# Integrating my Django REST API based extension into OpenedX container

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, openedx

I made a django extension according to these details:"**Stand up an instance of Open edX using either the Dockerized Tutor release or our https://gallery.ecr.aws/ibleducation/ibl-edx-ce (architected using Tutor).
Develop an extension that exposes a REST API endpoint and saves a greeting from the user (secure this endpoint with OAuth2 in the same way that Open edX secures its other API endpoints). This endpoint should do the following things with the user-submitted greeting:
Log it (it should be visible in the platform’s LMS logs).
Save it in the database (the greeting should be visible from the Django Admin).
If the greeting is “hello”, then the view of this API endpoint should call the original greeting endpoint again with “goodbye” as the parameter. This is to make sure that you can write an Open edX view that can make an OAuth2-secured API call with a client ID, a client secret and an access token. Of course, if your code calls this endpoint with “hello” again then it’ll be recursive and things will crash.**"

And now the steps where OpenedX is involed are left only please someone guide me through it.

I created a docker container using the image link provided above now I want to put the extension in it or whatever the instruction says. Moreover when I started the docker container the logs said translation file not found.....I tried everything but nothing worked.

Comment: Hi there please organize your post properly, include also some issue related images or any possible share link~

Comment: I just want to complete the task in the bold......no prior knowledge of docker....I made the django app now just want to integrate it into the OpenedX platform

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing it in the recommended way by edX. Here is the link which will guide you on how to do it quickly.
https://github.com/cookiecutter-openedx/openedx-plugin-example

You can also use this architecture
https://github.com/openedx/edx-cookiecutters